# Pop-up-Notification-Panel box is not staying to the right

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am building a simple *vertical notification panel* like the Stack Overflow notification panel. But the *pop-up is not staying to the right. When I halve the *browser window* then it is working fine. But when I make the browser window full then the *pop-up* is going to left, I mean, the pop-up box is not staying to the right where the open button is.

```js
$(".myNotification .icon_wrap").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
   // $(".myProfile").removeClass("active");
});

$(".show_all .link").click(function(){
  $(".myNotification").removeClass("active");
  $(".popup").show();
});

$(".close, .shadow").click(function(){
  $(".popup").hide();
});

$(".myB").click(function(){
  $(".myNotification").removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.myNavbar .profile_dd,
.notification_dd{
  right: -150px;
  max-width: -20px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 2em;
  width: 350px;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_left .logo a{
    font-family: 'Trade Winds';
   font-size: 20px;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right{
   display: flex;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right img{
  width: 35px;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right .icon_wrap{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right .myNotification{
  margin-left: 550px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .myNavbar .navbar_right .myNotificatio {
        margin-right: 550px;
    }
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right .myNotification .icon_wrap{
  font-size: 28px;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right .myProfile,
.myNavbar .navbar_right .myNotification{
  position: relative;
}

.myNavbar .myProfile .profile_dd ul li .btn{
    height: 32px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    background: #3b80f9;
    width: 125px;
    margin: 5px auto 15px;
}

.myNavbar .myProfile .profile_dd ul li .btn:hover{
  background: #6593e4;
}

.myNavbar .myProfile.active .profile_dd,
.myNavbar .myNotification.active .notification_dd{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
        " crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="myNavbar">
  <div class="navbar_right">
    <myDiv class="myNotification" id="Notif">
      <a class="icon_wrap" action=""><i class="far fa-bell"></i></a>

      <div class="notification_dd">
        This is Notification
      </div>
    </myDiv>
  </div>
</div>
```

**What have I tried? -**

I have also tried:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .notification_dd {
    right: -150px;
  }
}
```

But it is also going to left.

**What am I trying to do? -**

I am trying to make pop-notification stable to right right below the button and that doesn't change to left.

As you see, that *the problem* is not showing in the `snippet`. But you can try in your machine.

Comment: have a try to add `width: 100%` for `.myNotification`

Comment: You mean at `.myNavbar .profile_dd,.notification_dd` ? And Should i remove `width: 350px` ?

Comment: try here `.myNavbar .navbar_right .myNotification {margin-left: 550px; width: 100%;}`

Comment: Sorry, I run your code snippet and add above width, it does move to the right.

Comment: When i run the code with `width: 100%` then `right-margin`  is increased automatically

Comment: give a try removing `display: flex;` from `.navbar_right` and `right: 150px` from `.notification_dd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```js
$(".myNotification .icon_wrap").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
   // $(".myProfile").removeClass("active");
});

$(".show_all .link").click(function(){
  $(".myNotification").removeClass("active");
  $(".popup").show();
});

$(".close, .shadow").click(function(){
  $(".popup").hide();
});

$(".myB").click(function(){
  $(".myNotification").removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.myNavbar .profile_dd,
.notification_dd{
  right: 0px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 2em;
  width: 350px;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_left .logo a{
    font-family: 'Trade Winds';
   font-size: 20px;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right{
   display: flex;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right img{
  width: 35px;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right .icon_wrap{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right .myNotification{
  margin-left: 550px;
  width: 100%;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right .myNotification .icon_wrap{
  font-size: 28px;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right .myProfile,
.myNavbar .navbar_right .myNotification{
  position: relative;
}

.myNavbar .myProfile .profile_dd ul li .btn{
    height: 32px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    background: #3b80f9;
    width: 125px;
    margin: 5px auto 15px;
}

.myNavbar .myProfile .profile_dd ul li .btn:hover{
  background: #6593e4;
}

.myNavbar .myProfile.active .profile_dd,
.myNavbar .myNotification.active .notification_dd{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
    " crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="myNavbar">
    <div class="navbar_right">
        <myDiv class="myNotification" id="Notif">
        <a class="icon_wrap" action=""><i class="far fa-bell"></i></a>

            <div class="notification_dd">
                This is Notification
            </div>
        </myDiv>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's Working But It's little bit on the right, I mean it is increasing the page to the right

Comment: you mean when you run snippet code in the answer ?

Comment: I meant, your code in the browser. Just a little bit to the right, If it can move to left about `5px` then everything will be good ( In half screen ), ( Full screen is fine )

Comment: is there `right: -150px;` in your code, i changed it to `right: 0px;`

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What did you change and why? Why do you think it would work? - For example, have you carried out some testing, some of whose results you could share? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69871203/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).